# What is wrong with this bash script (cron + mysql)

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

Im using a bash script (sync.sh), used by cron, that is supposed to sync a file to a MySQL database. It works by copying a file from automatically uploaded location, parse it by calling SQL script which calls other MySQL internally stored scripts, and at the end emails a report text file as an attachment.

But, seems like something is not working as nothing happens to MySQL databases. All other commands are executed (first line and last line: copy initial file and e-mail sending).
MySQL command when run separately works perfectly.
Server is Ubuntu 16.04.
Cron job is run as root user and script is part of crontab for root user.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -u /home/admin/web/mydomain.com/public_html/dailyxchng/warehouse.txt /var/lib/mysql-files
mysql_pwd=syncit4321
cd /home/admin/web/mydomain.com/sync
mysql -u sync -p$mysql_pwd --database=database_name -e "call sp_sync_report();" > results.txt
echo "<h2>Report date $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')</h2><br/><br/> <strong>results.txt</strong> is an attached file which contains sync report." | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "Report date $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')" -a results.txt -- recipient@mydomain.com
```

Comment: Could you add the crontab line that you use to call the script?

Comment: Have you tried to put /usr/bin/mysql instead of mysql?

Comment: @A.Villegas
Crontab command is: 
55 2 * * * /home/admin/web/mydomain.com/sync/sync.sh

Comment: @nacho I didn't. Should I try it?

Comment: @Wed did you add your cron in a user who has the permissions? Could you try to log your cronjob output as following `55 2 * * * /home/admin/web/mydomain.com/sync/sync.sh >> /var/log/test.log 2>&1` and share file output?

Comment: @AlvaroNiño
Log file contains only one line. 
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Comment: yup, it executes it now that a path is added  /usr/bin/mysql

Comment: Hi, you have this output once you have fixed the link for MySQL as `/usr/bin/mysql`, my comment was a general recommendation for cron troubleshooting, if you have another problem using cron, try to log the output it might help you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cron will execute the script using a very stripped environment.  you probably want to add the full path to the mysql command to the cron script

you can find the full path by

```
which mysql
```

at the prompt, 
or you can add an expanded path to the cron invocation

```
1 2 * * * PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH scriptname
```

Comment: It should be `/usr/bin/mysql`

Comment: yes, I was attempting to make the point about cron's environment being stripped so you need to give full paths, by giving an incorrect path, the poster will see an error, and by giving the solution to finding the correct path the poster will correct the error.  Give the poster the tools, not the answer.